# MYSQL doesn't use index when using NOT IN

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, indexing

I have a table where there is an index for a column, so a query like this:

```
select * from table where id in (...)
```

using the index properly.

However if I use the opposite:

```
select * from table where id not in (...)
```

then the index is not used. The problem is the table have over 100 thousand rows, so a full table scan is very costly. The NOT IN part is not small, it could eliminate about 3/4 of the rows from the table, so it would make sense for the optimizer to use those ids and the index to eliminate rows and run a full table scan only on the rest. But it's not happening according to EXPLAIN.

Is there a way to make MYSQL to use the index in the second case?

Answer (score 1):

I just made a test database with random ids and used NOT IN on a few lines, it however did use the index.
It's possible MySQL thinks it's better in your case to not use the index, for example due to the distribution of your NOT IN, perhaps the datatype or perhaps it's just your version of MySQL.

It is however possible to force a query to use an index, as explained on this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html).

In your case your query would become:

```
select * from table FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY) where id not in (...)
```

Comment: mysql uses run-time heuristics to choose which index to use or whether to use a table walk instead.  The same mysql version, in faact even the same table, can toggle between one and the other.  I had a query that usually took 1 ms to run, but every few hundred calls it took 4-500 ms.  I tracked it to a different explain on the slow-running version.

Comment: Correct, MySQL determines it at run-time per query. Exactly my point :) However if the original poster wants to specifically use the key the FORCE INDEX should make MySQL use the index.

Answer (score 0):

the list of ids tells mysql which ones to skip, but to find what other ids exist in the table it must do a full table scan anyway, so that's what it does.  I don't believe mysql is smart enough to diff the primary key index against the column index.

You could do that yourself in the query, however -- you can include a nested query that pulled up the ids to return, and select only those rows.  The nested query could use the primary key index.  Something like

```
select * from table join (select id from table where id not in (...)) t using(id)
```

The nested query is only looking at the primary keys, it'll use the index.  The select is pulling up specific rows by primary key, it too will use the index.

Comment: Although the list of ids only tell which ones to skip, mysql can still select the ids it still does have to select from the index. So your statement is not fully correct.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking of an arbitrary column index.  If it's the id column itself then it should be able to walk just the primary index, yes.